# Excel: How do I compare 4 columns with repetitions?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, comparison, if

I have 4 columns. A,B,X,Y.
How do I compare all 4?
I want to create column Z where if A == X and the corresponding value B == Y, the result is 1. It is zero otherwise, how do I do that? Thanks

| A | B | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Phone | Red | Phone | Blue | 1 |
| Phone | Blue | Phone | Yellow | 1 |
| Phone | Yellow | Phone | Green | 0 |

Comment: This is unclear. For your first line you indicate `Z:1`, as indeed `A:Phone` equals `X:Phone`, but `B:Red` does not equal `Y:Blue`.

Comment: I am testing if value A and its corresponding value B exist in any range of X and Y, is this more clear? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=--(COUNTIFS(A:A,X1,B:B,Y1)>0)
```

Basically if the `COUNTIFS()` finds a match it will be greater than 0.  The `--` turns the `TRUE`/`FALSE` to `1`/`0` respectively

[image]